# How to make sure the following function did not over-allocate?

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory, malloc

I'm trying to make a function that gets number of columns and rows (width and height), build a 2D matrix, and then return the address of Matrix[0][0] back to a pointer in the original caller-function.

```
int **allocateMatrix(int width, int height) // function that allocate 
//memory for 2D matrix and check that memory allocation was successful
{
    int **Matrix;
    int row;
    Matrix = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*height); 
    if (!Matrix)
    {
        printf("failed to allocate memory. this program is over.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (row = 0; row < height; row++)    
    {   Matrix[row] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*width);     
      if (!Matrix[row])
      { 
        printf("failed to allocate memory. this program is over.\n");
        exit(1);
      }
    }
    return Matrix;
}
```

during the allocating i watched the whole thing through the debugger and it seems to create a way-too-big matrix then i intended, and an unexpected behavior in general.
such as: height =5, width =5, 
though Matrix[0][30] - exist and reachable.

moreover, Im not sure about the address im returning.

Comment: @Ofer Bar Oz, What did you expect `Matrix[0][30]` to do?  Did you expect C to catch the coding mistake?

Comment: there's no need to cast the result of a malloc since `void *`gets promoted automatically

Comment: Suggest `Matrix[row] = calloc (width, sizeof *Matrix[row])` as allocation with `calloc` will zero all bytes in `Matrix[row]` initializing all elements `0` preventing *Undefined Behavior* on inadvertent access of an uninitialized element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no problems with your allocation. In C if you go outside the boundaries and you're lucky you get a segmentation fault signal and the program terminates (if you haven't installed a particular signal handler for this signal), but if you land on some valid memory you get access to that memory and risk to corrupt something.

As others said in the comments C won't catch coding mistakes but if you compile with the flags `-Wall -pedantic -g` the compiler will generate some warnings when something is off and some time it'll even give you an hint on how to fix the mistake. Learn also how to use `valgrind`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your allocation scheme, but there are a number of improvements than can be made. If your debugger is reporting a 30-element row is reachable -- there is something wrong with how you are looking at the information.

First, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714).

Avoid `exit` in allocation functions. The caller should have the option of gracefully handling the failure-to-allocate rather than your program exiting at that point. While `exit` is valid, it severely limits your options for handling the failure. Instead, return a valid pointer on success, or `NULL` otherwise, and let the caller handle the error. In the case of a failed allocation, it is up to you to `free()` all previous allocations before returning `NULL`.

Consider using `calloc` to allocate storage for `matrix[row]`. `calloc` sets all bytes allocated to zero effectively initializing each element for each row to `0` preventing *Undefined Behavior* on the inadvertent access of an uninitialized element after return.

Putting all the pieces together, you could do something similar to:

```
/* allocatematrix allocates storage for a width x height matrix of type int.
 * all elements are initialized zero. on success returns a pointer to pointer
 * to type, otherwise all allocations are freed and NULL is returned.
 */
int **allocatematrix (int width, int height)
{
    int **matrix;
    int row;    /* declare row in for loop declaration, unless c89 support needed */

    matrix = malloc (height * sizeof *matrix);  /* allocate pointers */
    if (!matrix) {                  /* validate */
        perror ("malloc-matrix");   /* malloc failure set errno, use it */
        return NULL;                /* evaluate return in caller */
    }

    for (row = 0; row < height; row++) {    /* for each pointer */
        matrix[row] = calloc (width, sizeof *matrix[row]);  /* alloc rows */
        if (!Matrix[row]) {         /* validate */
            perror ("calloc-matrix[row]");  /* ditto for calloc */
            while (row--)           /* loop over previous rows */
                free (matrix[row]); /* free previously allocated rows */
            free (matrix);          /* free pointers */
            return NULL;            /* evaluate return in caller */
        }
    }

    return matrix;  /* return initial pointer address */
}
```

(**note:** while not an error, C generally avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable and function names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you)

(**also note:** the use of `perror` instead of `printf` for error reporting. When a function sets `errno` on failure, `perror` should be used. Further it already provides output on `stderr`. If dealing with a failure where `errno` isn't set, the use `fprintf` (if a conversion is needed) or `fputs` otherwise and report the error on `stderr` instead of `stdout`)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.